# Solving inequation where one of the terms is a log

Tags: functions, inequality

I trying to find the value for which $n^2 -n +1$ is less than $ 6n\log_{2}{n} +2n $ where n is a power of $2$.

Trying it iteratively using a CAS you find that $n = 64$.

How can $n^2 -n +1 < 6n\log_{2}{n} +2n $ where n is a power of $2$ be solved analytically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Subtract $2n$ from both sides, and then divide them both by $n$. You have $n+\dfrac1n<6k+3$, where $k=\log_2n.~$ But $0<\dfrac1n\le1.~$ Since the linear function is far greater than the logarithmic function for all values of the argument except for the first few, you only have a few cases to check. Otherwise, you are left with solving $n=2^k\approx6k+3$, which can only be expressed analytically in terms of the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). In general, $a^k=Ak+B$ has the solution $k=-\dfrac BA-\dfrac{W(C)}{\ln a}$, where $C=-\dfrac{\ln a}{A~\sqrt[A]{a^B}}$ ; see the first [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Example_1).

Comment: In this case, you'll have to choose $W_{-1}(C)$ instead of $W_0(C)$. For the first, the value of *k* is around $0$; for the latter, you'll have $k\approx5$. Indeed, $2^5=32\approx6\cdot5+3=33$.